# AdWhirl or AdMob problem

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, admob

I tried to integrate AdWhirl with adMob on my iPad app. I just got a problem I can't fix.

The adMob ad has two types of ad , which are inside the app and outside the app(leave the app). My problem is that the ad will popup new view automatically without user action when adMob inside ad comes in.

I tried to debug this, the code will call adWhirlDidReceiveAd() firstly and then call adWhirlWillPresentFullScreenModal() immediately, so I don't know how to solve this.

Anyone has same problem? any help would be appreciate.

Peng

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got any response and I just fixed this problem.

Currently I used adMob 4.1.0, so I update to lastest version 4.1.1, then this problem has gone, don't know why.